# TYPO3: How to use external PHP libraries in Extbase Extension (no composer installation)

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I got TYPO3 v10.2 running without Composer. I am creating an extension and want to include some third party PHP libraries into my Extbase Extension. I already read in the TYPO3 docs that those should be placed in `Resources/Private/PHP/ThirdPartyLibrary` but how can I include them there ? Is it still possible with `composer require` or should I just download the third party library resources and unzip it there ? How can I use the namespace/Classes from the external Library in the Controller or general in my Extension ?
What is the best way to do this without AND with composer ? Would like to know both ways. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You can just use composer in your local environment.

1. `composer init`
2. `composer req <neded packages>`
3. `composer u`
4. Move the `vendor/` into your `your_extension/Resources/Private/PHP/ThirdPartyLibrary/`
5. Adjust the autoload path into the `vendor/` that you just moved.

#### You can have a look into the Shariff Extension

They placed the external library in `Resources/Private/Shariff/vendor/`

https://bitbucket.org/reelworx/rx_shariff/src/master/Resources/Private/Shariff/

#### And Autoload the files in

https://bitbucket.org/reelworx/rx_shariff/src/master/Classes/Shariff.php

#### Using the libraries in your controller

The libraries need to have namespaces already if you want to use them in your controller.

Since your in TYPO3 V10 you can use the new symfony dependency injection that is implemented into TYPO3 now: https://usetypo3.com/dependency-injection.html

**your_extension/Classes/Controller/YourController.php**

```php
/**
 * @var ThirdPartyLibrary
 */
protected $thirdPartyLibrary;

/**
 * @param ThirdPartyLibrary $thirdPartyLibrary
 */
public function __construct(ThirdPartyLibrary $thirdPartyLibrary)
{
    $this->thirdPartyLibrary = $thirdPartyLibrary;
}
```

**your_extension/Configuration/Services.yaml**

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    Vendor\Namespace\:
        resource: '../Resources/Private/PHP/ThirdPartyLibrary/*'
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to load the class for your library. I not sure which library your using.

Place the below code in your `ext_localconf.php`

```
<?php

$composerAutoloadFile = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('yourExtKey') . 'Resources/Private/PHP/ThirdPartyLibrary/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once($composerAutoloadFile);
```

Now, you can use the library class wherever you want to use it. Make sure you dump cache as well as autoload class from TYPO3 Backend!